# ParsingJSON without any keys in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm playing around with the twitter API and it's returning the following:

`[ 12345, 12345, 12345, 12345 ]`

How do I go about parsing this into an array or object?

I can't see how to do it using $.getJSON as there are no keys to reference the data with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need keys in this case, in your success function just loop through they array, for example:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, id) {
    alert('ID #' + i + ' is ' + id);
  });
});
```

They point is the object might *already* be an array, so just loop through it, it doesn't need to be `data.key[0]`, it may just be `data[0]`, which is what you have here :)

Comment: Thanks I tried the code out and it returns "a is null" using jQuery 1.4.2. Looking at firebug it's returning a 200 OK so there is something there.

Comment: @digital - That's a minified error, saying that `data` itself is null.  Are you viewing the response in your console, or trying the same URL in your browser manually?  If you're doing it manually, you might be hitting cross-domain issues in your actual AJAX request that you're unaware of...e.g. does your URL contain `?callback=?` to trigger JSONP behavior?

Answer (score 0):

you could use that return to create an array.

`$arr = [ 12345, 12345, 12345, 12345 ]`